# Could not initialize class io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, cucumber

I have a piece of Cucumber + JUNIT + Selenium WebDriver code to be used in JMeter for load testing.
Following is the piece of code:

```
package runner;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import cucumber.api.cli.Main;
import pageobjects.alinea.AssetsMetadataPage;

public class TestRunner{
private static Logger Log = LogManager.getLogger(AssetsMetadataPage.class);

public ClassLoader load;

public TestRunner(String str) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    
    this();
}
public TestRunner() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
// Test method is defined with Cucumber Main run method. 
// "-g" signifies glue code (package where the code is), "-t" signifies the tag.  The location of the feature file which defines the test scripts 


@Test
public void runTest() throws Throwable {
try {

        Main.run(new String[]{"-g", "step_definitions","-t", "@upload", "src/test/resources/features/addcontent.feature"}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        //log.info("Print");
        Log.info("Print");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
// Post Test what the JUNIT test needs to do
}
```

This is the feature file:

```
@Upload
Scenario: User upload the image
Given navigate to folder and upload a picture
```

and imported these jar into the lib folder of jmeter:

```
junit-4.13.jar
cobertura-1.8.jar
mockito-core-3.5.5.jar
cucumber-core-5.7.0.jar
cucumber-java-5.7.0.jar
cucumber-junit-5.7.0.jar
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
gherkin-15.0.2.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
```

When I try to run from Eclipse, there's no issue, the execution is completed without any glitch.
But when i run this from jmeter getting below error:

```
**Error -- runTest(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): io/cucumber/plugin/SummaryPrinter
Trace -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/SummaryPrinter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption$1.<init>(PluginOption.java:37)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.PluginOption.<clinit>(PluginOption.java:36)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptions.addDefaultFormatterIfAbsent(RuntimeOptions.java:60)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.build(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:132)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:61)
    at runner.TestRunner.runTest(TestRunner.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase.runTest(JUnitSampler.java:595)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.sample(JUnitSampler.java:395)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.plugin.SummaryPrinter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 28 more**
```

**

Am I missing something to add in jmeter for Cucumber options? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You have the wrong depencies. Use maven to download the correct ones including the correct transitive depencies.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Hi, i have downloaded it from the maven only...still what dependency is wrong in the above list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error NoClassDefFoundError while running Junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904896/error-noclassdeffounderror-while-running-junit-test)

Comment: You say "[you] downloaded it from the maven", which seems to indicate that you don't actually use Maven or Gradle to build and run your code, but downloaded the files yourself from Maven Central (or another Maven repository).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel ...yes..In jmeter we have to put the jars in lib folder so i downloaded it from maven central repository

Comment: The problem with doing that is that you may have missed the dependencies of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to run your Cucumber tests in JMeter as JMeter's [JUnit Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) uses [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) in order to call the functions annotated with [JUnit annotations](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/package-summary.html) and Cucumber in its turn generates Java classes from the feature files in the runtime and this behaviour is not compatible with JMeter.

So instead of using real browsers for performance testing I would rather recommend converting your Cucumber test into a "pure" JMeter test, it's enough to run it via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) by [configuring the proxy in your Selenium code](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) and you will get [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which will perform the file upload.

Just make sure to copy the file(s) your Cucumber test will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation prior to execution otherwise JMeter will not be able to properly catch the request, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

And last but not the least, modern browsers are very resource intensive, for example [Firefox 78 requires 1 CPU core and 2GB of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/78.0/system-requirements/) **per browser instance** and with JMeter you can easily simulate hundreds of virtual users at cost of a single browser