# What is the difference of cucumber -Core and Cucumber-java8 Dependencies?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am new to cucumber , I am confused of the required dependencies . I will be using Lambda expressions and JUnit.

I have added below dependencies.

1. cucumber - Junit
2. Cucumber -Java8
3. Cucumber - Core
4. Junit

I'm not sure of the purpose of cucumber -Core, Cucumber-Java8 and Junit , Cucumber -Junit dependencies.

Could you please help me to understand the purpose of each dependencies

Comment: Are you using a build tool like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I am using maven

Comment: You only have to add cucumber-java8 and cucumber-junit as dependencies then. One is for the lambda step definitions, the other for running cucumber with junit. All others are transitive dependencies (google it). This isn't for your question but have a look at it anyway:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61904896/error-noclassdeffounderror-while-running-junit-test/61908459#61908459

Comment: I have added "Junit-4" along with Cucumber-Java8, Cucumber-Junit.  

It's because I think, @RunWith annotation is from "Junit-4" dependency and not from Cucumber-Junit. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That assumption is correct. But try removing the dependency and study the output from `mvn dependency:tree`.