# Test runner class of cucumber is not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, rest-assured

I'm working on an API automation project using rest assured and cucumber, I created it in java type not maven because I created it on a server machine that doesn't have access to the internet.
I used the below jars

- Cucumber plugin version 231.8109.90
- Cucumber core version 7.11.2
- Cucumber java version 7.11.2
- Cucumber TestNg version 7.11.2
  But when I ran the test, I got an error and I don't know what the problem is. Can someone help me?
  **Error:**

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301/bin/java

 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/event/EventPublisher

 

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)`your text`
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:65)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:381)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:319)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 38 more

 

[Utils] [WARN] The test method 'io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario' will be skipped since its data provider 'scenarios' returned an empty array or iterator.
```

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/feature_files",glue = {"step_definitions"},plugin = {"pretty","html"})
//Run Cucumber file every detected feature as separated test
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Comment: Looks like the JVM can't find the specified class at runtime. Ensure that the cucumber jar is correctly linked to your project

Comment: You are missing several dependencies. Even if you can't use Maven in your CI system due to a lack of internet, you can use it on your local machine to collect all the dependencies. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61908459/3945473